# How to split string of char and integer in such a way that corresponding number gets added up for same chars present in string?

Tags: java, string

For eg if we have a string like

```
"a2b7j5k78f34a23b28f9"
```

then the output should be

```
"a25b35j5k78f343"
```

so the numbers corresponding to each characters gets added, each character can have max to max a 3 digit number with it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that might you are expecting...

```
import java.util.*; import java.io.*;

public class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<Character,Integer> mp = new HashMap<>();
        String s = in.nextLine();
        Character c = null;
        int num = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();++i){
            if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))){
                num = num*10+Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(i)+"");
            }else{
                if(c!=null){
                    if(mp.containsKey(c)){
                        mp.put(c,mp.get(c)+num );
                    }else{
                        mp.put(c,num);
                    }
                }
                c = s.charAt(i);
                num = 0;
            }
        }
        if(c!=null){
            if(mp.containsKey(c)){
                mp.put(c,mp.get(c)+num );
            }else{
                mp.put(c,num);
            }
        }
        for(Map.Entry<Character,Integer> entry:mp.entrySet()){
            System.out.print(entry.getKey()+""+entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

INPUT: `a2b7j5k78f34a23b28f9`
OUTPUT: `a25b35f43j5k78`